# Add printf into a Wordpress 'do_shortcode'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that is showing the url of a file meta key:

```
$images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_of_user' );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
        $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $full_size, $thumb );
    }
}
```

Instead of showing just the URL in an HREF, i with it to play inside the WordPress default media player.

so i am using "do_shortcode" for "[video]". what i can't seem to do is to add the:

```
printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $full_size, $thumb );
```

Inside the do_shortcode. something like that:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[video width="100%" height="472" m4v="MY-VIDEO-URL"][/video]' ); ?>
```

i have tried doing this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[video width="100%" height="472" m4v="'%s', $full_size, $thumb"][/video]' ); ?>
```

But it dosn't seem to work.

I have also tried:

```
$images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_of_user' );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );

    }
}
```

And then:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode( '[video width="100%" height="472" m4v="'. wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'full' ) .'"][/video]' ); ?>
```

But this also don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
$images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_of_user' );
if ( $images ) {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id ) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );
        echo do_shortcode( '[video width="100%" height="472" m4v="'. $url .'"][/video]' ); ?>

    }
}
```